# Render SQL Server of type Image

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, express

I'm calling uncle on this. I have an app that I'm working on where I want to return an image that is stored in a SQL Server column of type `Image`.

I'm using a rest api to return the object and that is coming back fine.

[image: Here's what the json object looks like.]

And my HTML does a *ngFor waiting for the returned images.

```html
<div *ngIf="imagesFound">
    <ngb-carousel [interval]="1000" [wrap]="true" [keyboard]="true" >
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
          <img class="center-block" src="{{image.Image}}">
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
  </div>
```

I'm calling a method on click.

```js
searchImages(query: string){
    this.searching = true;
    return this._imageService.getImage(query).subscribe(
      data => this.handleSuccess(data),
      error => this.handleError,
      () => this.searching = false
    )
  }
  
  handleSuccess(data){
    if (data.recordset) {
      this.imagesFound = true;
      this.emptyData =false;
      this.images = data.recordset;
      console.log(data.recordset);
    } else {
      this.imagesFound = false;
      this.emptyData =true;
      console.log("no images found");
    }
  }
```

I get a broken image returned. I'm really stuck and could use some guidance. Anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: thanks, that's useful information.